# PL/SQL Execution Issue

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have gotten my procedure to compile and execute but i'm not getting any information inserted into my PURCHASEORDERS table from my IF statements like I thought I would.  Can anyone tell me what the issue is please?  Thanks!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE placeorder (inputDate IN DATE)
AS
CURSOR C1 IS
SELECT ir.itemId, ir.ORDERSAMEDAY, ir.ORDERNEXTDAY FROM INVENTORYREPORT ir WHERE 
ir.REPORTDATE = inputDate;

new_orderType PURCHASEORDERS.ORDERTYPE%TYPE;
ir_orderSameDay INVENTORYREPORT.ORDERSAMEDAY%TYPE;
ir_orderNextDay INVENTORYREPORT.ORDERNEXTDAY%TYPE;
ir_itemID INVENTORYREPORT.ITEMID%TYPE;
ir_pono CHAR(12 BYTE);
ir_poDate DATE;
ir_poQuantity NUMBER(6,0);



BEGIN
FOR  PURCHASEORDERS IN C1 LOOP

IF ir_orderSameDay > 0 THEN
 INSERT INTO PURCHASEORDERS VALUES (ir_pono, ir_poDate, ir_itemID, ir_poQuantity, '', 
'same_day');
 dbms_output.put_line('orderType: ' || 'Same Day');
END IF;

IF ir_orderSameDay = 0
THEN INSERT INTO ERROR_TAB VALUES (ir_itemID, 'No Same Day Order');
dbms_output.put_line('ItemID: ' || ir_itemID || 'No Same Day Order');
END IF;
END LOOP;

END placeorder;
/

exec placeorder('19-APR-18')
```

Comment: Did you commit ?

Comment: I tried adding a COMMITT after the END LOOP part and still didn't get anything inserted into the table.  Thanks for they tip to try!

Comment: So I guess that you have `time` part. Quick check: `CURSOR C1 IS
 SELECT ir.itemId, ir.ORDERSAMEDAY, ir.ORDERNEXTDAY FROM INVENTORYREPORT ir WHERE 
TRUNC(ir.REPORTDATE) = inputDate;`

Comment: Code you posted is invalid (mind you, `ir_` vs. `ir.`). It would help if you posted accurate information. Also, the procedure expects DATE as a parameter, but you provide a string - why? I'd rather use `exec placeorder(date '2018-04-19')` and make sure that this doesn't mess things up.

Comment: I tried highlighting that part and running it and inputDate is the parameter and isn't actually an existing column right now @ lad2025

Comment: @Littlefoot the date format in the reportDate column is in the format 19-APR-18.  The 'ir.' I'm using is for the cursor select statement whereas the 'ir_' is just what I'm naming my variables.  I'm not super experienced with pl/sql so I may just be doing dumb stuff

Answer (score 0):

You've declared some variables, but never put any value into them, so I removed all of them from the code.

Therefore, `IF ir_orderSameDay > 0 THEN` (as well as `... = 0`) will never be true as IR_ORDERSAMEDAY is NULL, and NULL is not larger nor equal to anything.

I think that you should include some other values into the SELECT statement (as I did in the following example).

Also, I'd suggest you to name all columns you're inserting in the `INSERT INTO` statement - it makes things clearer.

As of the "date" value you're mentioning - you're wrong. You might be seeing it as '19-APR-18', but that is a **string**. If you're passing dates, then you'd better really do it, and not rely on implicit datatype conversion.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE placeorder (inputDate IN DATE)
  AS
BEGIN
  FOR cur_r in (SELECT ir.itemId, 
                       ir.ORDERSAMEDAY, 
                       ir.ORDERNEXTDAY,
                       -- the next values added by LF
                       ir.pono, 
                       ir.podate, 
                       ir.poquantity
                FROM INVENTORYREPORT ir 
                WHERE  ir.REPORTDATE = inputDate)
  LOOP
    IF cur_r.ordersameday > 0 THEN
       INSERT INTO PURCHASEORDERS VALUES 
         (cur_r.pono, cur_r.poDate, cur_r.itemID, cur_r.poQuantity, '', 'same_day');
       dbms_output.put_line('orderType: ' || 'Same Day');
    END IF;

    IF cur_r.orderSameDay = 0 THEN 
       INSERT INTO ERROR_TAB VALUES 
         (cur_r.itemID, 'No Same Day Order');
       dbms_output.put_line('ItemID: ' || cur_r.itemID || 'No Same Day Order');
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END placeorder;
/

exec placeorder(date '2018-04-19');
or
exec placeorder(to_date('19.04.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy'));
```

Comment: thanks i'll take a look at this try to implement your suggestions.  Appreciate it!

Comment: whne I tried simply running that script it shows 'cur_r use is invalid'.  The two instances where at the beginning of r the IF statements.  Are those two instances referring to the cursor select statement?

Comment: Sorry, went to sleep. I've noticed (in your own answer) that you used `exec placeorder(to_date('21-APR-18', 'DD-MON-YYYY'));` - format mask doesn't match data - there are 2 digits for year (18), but you applied 4-digits mask (YYYY) to it. Don't do that; I showed you the correct way. Also, as it turns out that you can't make it work, please, provide CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data so that we'd see what you have and - hopefully - assist.

Answer (score 0):

@Littlefoot I've tried to make some changes according to your suggestions and I've also converted that date column for the INVENTORYREPORT table so my cursor actually pulls data I believe.  Once again it compiles and executes but I can't figure out why it's not inserting any rows into PURCHASEORDERS..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE placeorder (inputDate IN DATE)
AS
BEGIN

FOR cur_r in (SELECT ITEMID, 
                   ORDERSAMEDAY, 
                   ORDERNEXTDAY,
                   BEGINNINGINVENTORYLEVEL, 
                   REPORTDATE, 
                   CONSUMPTIONQUANTITY
            FROM INVENTORYREPORT 
            WHERE  REPORTDATE = inputDate)

 LOOP
IF cur_r.ordersameday > 0 THEN
   INSERT INTO PURCHASEORDERS VALUES 
     (cur_r.itemid, cur_r.reportdate, cur_r.beginninginventorylevel, cur_r.consumptionquantity, '', 'same_day');
   dbms_output.put_line('orderType: ' || 'Same Day');
END IF;

IF cur_r.orderSameDay = 0 THEN 
   INSERT INTO ERROR_TAB VALUES 
     (cur_r.itemID, 'No Same Day Order');
   dbms_output.put_line('ItemID: ' || cur_r.itemID || 'No Same Day Order');
END IF;
END LOOP;
END placeorder;
/

exec placeorder(to_date('21-APR-18', 'DD-MON-YYYY'));
```

Comment: maybe cur_r.orderSameDay is null or it  is less than 0. try to put a DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('cur_r.orderSameDay: '||cur_r.orderSameDay) before the IF condition.

Comment: @eifla001 I added the statement where you specified and it still compiled and executed the same but I don't see anything shown on the tables I need.  Does that mean that my value for that variable is NULL?

Comment: did something showed up in your DBMS_OUTPUT window when you ran the procedure?

Comment: Nothing showed up in the DBMS Output window when I executed the procedure

Comment: ah, okay, try to run the query in the for loop where report date is april 21, 2018. If that query return no rows, then that could be the reason why no records was inserted, otherwise, you forgot to turn on the DBMS_OUTPUT (serveroutput)

Comment: @eifla001 I tried running a separate query with SELECT * from that table with that dat and I pull everything.  I did put in the line "SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;" as well

Comment: ok, so there is a data, did you find the value of ORDERSAMEDAY?

Comment: Nothing showed up in the dbms output window when I tried that.  I noticed there's a chat but I'm not high enough reputation to use it.. is there any other way I could bounce ideas off of you as well?

Comment: i believe no need for a chat app in this problem. I believe in your skills that you can solve this, and I suggest you should take more time answering your question than making others figure it out.